# How to show processes of specific users in htop

Tags: command-line, process, htop

Is there a way to only list processes of given users in htop? I know that I can select a single user by using `htop -u USERNAME`, but is there a way to select more than a one person?

Comment: Doesn't look like it's possible. File a feature request at https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/issues

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you; First get processid with ps command with u option then, use htop -p commands as below;

```
#!/bin/bash
n=0; 
while (( n++ < 3 )); do 
{ sleep 3; killall htop;}&
htop -p $(ps -u root -u youruser  | awk 'BEGIN{ORS=","} {print $1}') 
done
```

Comment: Well, it does not show me, if any new process is started, does it?

Comment: @AdamHunyadi Yes, you are right, maybe delay option help you, I updated ans.

Comment: -d only refreshes the htop call, but the process list remains the same.

Comment: @AdamHunyadi ; I updated ans. maybe this can help you.